# событие ухода со страницы yii

Tags: php, yii

Пишу сайт на Yii 1.1.5 версии. Использую форму с ajaxuploader - загрузчиком файлов, например я загрузил пару файлов и потом просто ушел со страницы и они остались лежать на сервере. Я хочу их удалять если пользователь не сохранил их и просто покинул форму. Возможно есть решение на самом фрейворке или хотя-бы скрипт

Answer (score 1):

Помечай сначала как .tmp, потом создай daily скрипт на сервере, который будет их удалять если они лежат больше дня.

Comment: спасибо, только не знаю как это на практике реализовать